# How to tilt a DEM?

Tags: dem

I'm working on relictic fluvial terraces which have been tilted a few degrees during tectonic exhumation. I want to extract surfaces (terraces) with a certain slope angle and within a certain range of height.

How can I correct my DEM for this?

Comment: what software are you on?

Comment: arcmap 10.5 desktop